# Android app not connecting to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: react-native, https, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a mobile app using react native android app and ASP.NET Core Web API. The app is tested in Android studio simulator.

Everything was working fine until I included `network_security_config` as shown below (without this configuration app is not connecting to prod server):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->  
            <certificates src="system" />  
            <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->  
            <certificates src="user" /> 
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But after this change, I am not able to connect to my `localhost` web API (https connection).

What are the changes I need to make on network config to allow https://localhost connection